# what is auth.guard.ts and AuthenticationService in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './_services';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AuthGuard` is a class which implements the interface `CanActivate`, **to decide whether the user has access/permission to view specific `page / route / path` in the application or not**.

This will be useful when we need **authentication/authorization based control** over the application.

Please refer https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate